# Tirar link de CSS com Regex

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, regex

Bom dia pessoal, ao puxar o html da pagina todo em string ele também traz alguns links de referência:

```
<link href="~/Content/item/item.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

Eu já retirei as tags  e , mas preciso retirar esta e não estou conseguindo, o código que utilizo para retirar as tags de script e style é este:

```
var regex = new Regex("(\\<script(.+?)\\</script\\>)|(\\<style(.+?)\\</style\\>)",
            RegexOptions.Singleline | RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
        HTMLemString = regex.Replace(HTMLemString, "");
```

Se alguém puder me ajudar eu agradeço.

Comment: O que você quer deixar?

Comment: Todo o HTML mas sem estes links do CSS

Comment: Ttenta essa regex: <link[^>]*> ela da match com todas as tags <link/>

Comment: funcionou obrigado :D

Answer (score 0):

Conforme mencionado nos comentários da pergunta, você pode incluir o trecho `(<link[^>]*>)` em sua expressão regular. Esta expressão obtem todos as tags `link`, conforme exemplos:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="cg.css">
<link href="~/Content/item/item.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

Você pode ver/testar este regex [aqui](https://regex101.com/r/71wqr3/1).